# Simplest way to change multiple elements in a Seq in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a template sequence like this:

```
val template = Seq(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

I have another sequence which contains the index should be modified, like this:

```
val indices = Seq(1,3,7)
```

I want to modify the template sequence, in the way that, if the element's index is in the indices sequence, then replace the element to 1.

So the output should look like:

```
(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0)
```

What is the simplest way to implement this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foldLeft` in your solution repeatedly rebuilds the sequence. This could be inefficient if the sequence is for example a `List` and all `indices` point to the end of the list.

You could also achieve it without repeatedly rebuilding the collection:

```
val indexSet = indices.toSet
val result = template.zipWithIndex.map{ case (v, i) =>
  if (indexSet contains i) 1 else v
}
```

For a `List` this solution would be amortized `O(n)`, because checking whether an integer is in the set of indices is amortized `O(1)`.

Maybe there are also use-cases where your solution is preferable, it's not so clear for general `Seq`s.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it by myself:

```
indices.foldLeft(template)((b, a) => b.updated(a, 1))
```